# JS AM/PM times always show AM

Tags: javascript, time

I am making a simple time calculator in javascript. I have converted the times into 12-hour instead of 24 hour time for simplicity, however the code I have for calculating am/pm always shows am. Any reason why this would be happening?

Here is my code:

```
function solveTime(x) {
    var suffixSolve = (utcHours + x) % 24;
    var suffix = "am";
    if (utcHours > 12) {
        var suffix = "pm";
    }
    if (utcMinutes == 0) {
        utcMinutesLead = "00";
    }
    if (utcMinutes < 10) {
        utcMinutesLead = "0" + utcMinutes;
    }
    var timeSolve = (((utcHours + x) + 11) % 12 + 1);
    var timeTotal = timeSolve + ":" + utcMinutesLead + " " + suffix;
    var utcMod = x;
    if (utcMod > 0) {
       utcMod = "+" + utcMod;
    }
    document.getElementById(x).innerHTML = "(UTC" + utcMod + ") " + timeTotal;
}
```

and here is the code behind utcHours

```
var masterTimeUTC = new Date();
var utcHours = masterTimeUTC.getUTCHours();
var utcMinutes = masterTimeUTC.getUTCMinutes();
var utcSeconds = masterTimeUTC.getUTCSeconds();
var utcMinutesLead = masterTimeUTC.getUTCMinutes();
```

Example here: http://codepen.io/markgamb/pen/gwGkbo

Comment: What is the x your passing as parameter

Comment: utc modifier, ex: -8 for utc-8

Comment: Can you explain me with a realtime example?

Comment: Sure, Basically I use it to solve for time, and x is the utc modifier (it can be 0, or any negative or positive number). Example here: http://codepen.io/markgamb/pen/gwGkbo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you should be checking whether `suffixSolve` is greater than 12 instead of `utcHours`, because `utcHours` does not change due to the value of `x`. Since you can shift the hours forward and backwards, I created a variable `shift` to handle that.

```js
function solveTime(x) {
  if (x < 0) {
    var shift = 24 + x;
  } else {
    var shift = x;
  }

  var suffixSolve = (utcHours + shift) % 24;
  var suffix = "am";
  if (suffixSolve > 12) {
    suffix = "pm";
  }
  if (utcMinutes == 0) {
    utcMinutesLead = "00";
  }
  if (utcMinutes < 10) {
    utcMinutesLead = "0" + utcMinutes;
  }
  var timeSolve = (((utcHours + x) + 11) % 12 + 1);
  var timeTotal = timeSolve + ":" + utcMinutesLead + " " + suffix;
  var utcMod = x;
  if (utcMod > 0) {
    utcMod = "+" + utcMod;
  }
  document.getElementById(x).innerHTML = "(UTC" + utcMod + ") " + timeTotal;
}
var masterTimeUTC = new Date();
var utcHours = masterTimeUTC.getUTCHours();
var utcMinutes = masterTimeUTC.getUTCMinutes();
var utcSeconds = masterTimeUTC.getUTCSeconds();
var utcMinutesLead = masterTimeUTC.getUTCMinutes();
solveTime(4);
solveTime(0);
solveTime(-8);
```

```html
<div id="4"></div>
<div id="-8"></div>
<div id="0"></div>
```